# 'Dice di sì' o 'dice sì', a cosa serve quel 'di'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Charo: "Elberich, sai che domani c'è pioggia?"

Elberich: "Chissà, comunque Josh dice *di* sì."

È corretto—o, per ragioni idiomatiche, magari necessario—quel *di* fra 'dice' e 'sì' o potrebbe essere omesso?

E se lo si omette, ammesso non sia necessario,  c'è qualche variazione di significato o enfasi?

Comment: Io ho sempre ascoltato/letto "dire di sì", "credere di sì", ecc. Nella mia lingua però queste tipo di espressioni si fanno senza preposizione ("dir sí" o "dir que sí").

Comment: Usare il "di" è sicuramente corretto e idiomatico. Rimuoverlo al di là del corretto o meno in ogni caso suonerebbe *molto* peggio,mi verrebbe da interpretare "comunque Josh dice sì" come un'affermazione completamente scollegata da ciò di cui si sta parlando, come farei se la frase fosse "Chissà, comunque Josh dice che le temperature saranno basse".In altre parole in quel modo interpreterei quel "sì" come se si stesse riferirendo ad un qualsiasi altro "sì" detto da Josh a proposito di qualcos'altro e non al "sì" detto da Josh a proposito del se pioverà o meno.Credo che sia sbagliato rimuoverlo.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

***[Dire di sì](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dire/)*** è un'espressione idiomatica che significa:

> - acconsentire, dare risposta affermativa. (Treccani.it)

- Dicendo di sì Josh dice di essere anche lui del parere che domani piove.

Omettendo la preposizione "di", l'espressione assume un significato letterale e verrebbe usata in un dialogo diretto.

- Cosa dice Josh?
- Josh dice  "sì".

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @Josh61 ed aggiungo: il Nuovo Ragazzini/Biagi Dizionario Inglese/Italiano (1991) dice: "dire di no, to refuse; to say one won't (wouldn't ecc.) - dire di sì, to accept; to agree; to say one will (would ecc.)".

Answer (score 0):

Credo che abbiano significati diversi , si dice :"Josh dice "sì"" quando Josh chiaramente dice la parola "sì" , però si dice "Josh dice di sì" quando Josh dice quello che si riferisce all'approvazione.